# Error when running a bulk update to trigger a trigger: Required fields are missing: [Status]: [Status] (LabsActionPlans): []

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

I have created a trigger on the **Task** object which executes `afterUpdate`, `afterInsert` and `beforeDelete`. This trigger will get the relevant Opportunity using the `WhatId` field on the task, run some logic, and update a field on the Opportunity.

This trigger works fine for a single Task being updated, but if I try to update say 100 Task records at once (so the trigger is executed for each and the relevant Opportunities are updated), I get the following error:

> Required fields are missing: [Status]: [Status] (LabsActionPlans): []

I have checked there are **no Tasks without a Status**.

Here is my trigger:

```
trigger SetLatestTaskOpenOnOpp on Task (after insert, after update, before delete) {
    List<Task> tasksForThisTrigger;
    List<Task> originalTasksForThisTrigger;
    Task currentTask;
    List<Id> oppIds;
    try
    {
        tasksForThisTrigger = Trigger.New;
        if (Trigger.isDelete)
        {
            tasksForThisTrigger = Trigger.Old;
        }
        originalTasksForThisTrigger = tasksForThisTrigger;
        oppIds = getOppIdsForTasks(tasksForThisTrigger);
        if (oppIds.size() == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        system.debug(oppIds);
        tasksForThisTrigger = [SELECT Id, WhatId, CreatedDate, Status FROM Task WHERE WhatId IN: oppIds AND TaskSubtype = 'Task'];
        system.debug(tasksForThisTrigger);
        List<Opportunity> opps = [SELECT Id, Latest_Task_Open__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN: oppIds];
        Map<Id, List<Task>> mapOfTasksByOppId = getMapOfTasksByOppId(tasksForThisTrigger);
        Map<Id, Opportunity> mapOfOpps = new Map<ID, Opportunity>([SELECT Id, Latest_Task_Open__c FROM Opportunity WHERE ID IN: oppIds]);
        
        // need this list as we only need to go through every opp/s task list once, no matter how many tasks are related to it
        List<Id> oppsIdsThatHaveBeenProcessed = new List<Id>();
        
        List<Opportunity> oppsToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();
        
        
        if (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)
        {
            for (Task t : Trigger.new) {
                if (!oppsIdsThatHaveBeenProcessed.contains(t.WhatId))
                {
                    oppsIdsThatHaveBeenProcessed.add(t.WhatId);  
                    List<Task> tasksForThis = mapOfTasksByOppId.get(t.WhatId);
                    
                    if (tasksForThis == null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    
                    Task latestTaskInIteration;
                    for (Task taskForThis: tasksForThis)
                    {
                        currentTask = taskForThis;
                        if (latestTaskInIteration == null)
                        {
                            latestTaskInIteration = taskForThis;
                        }
                        
                        if (taskForThis.CreatedDate > latestTaskInIteration.CreatedDate)
                        {
                            latestTaskInIteration = taskForThis;
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Opportunity opp = mapOfOpps.get(latestTaskInIteration.WhatId);
                    if (latestTaskInIteration.Status != 'Completed')
                    {
                        opp.Latest_Task_Open__c = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        opp.Latest_Task_Open__c = false;
                    }
                    
                    oppsToUpdate.add(opp); 
                }    
            }
            
        }
        
        if (Trigger.isDelete)
        {
            system.debug(Trigger.new);
            for (Task t : Trigger.old) {
                if (!oppsIdsThatHaveBeenProcessed.contains(t.WhatId))
                {
                    oppsIdsThatHaveBeenProcessed.add(t.WhatId);   
                    List<Task> tasksForThis = mapOfTasksByOppId.get(t.WhatId);
                    
                    if (tasksForThis == null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    
                    Task latestTaskInIteration;
                    Opportunity opp = null;
                    for (Task taskForThis: tasksForThis)
                    {
                        currentTask = taskForThis;
                        if (opp == null)
                        {
                            opp = mapOfOpps.get(taskForThis.WhatId);
                        }   
                        
                        // if this record exists in Trigger.OldMap, then it's been deleted
                        Boolean isDeleted = Trigger.OldMap.get(taskForThis.Id) != null;
                        if (isDeleted)
                        {
                            system.debug('isDeleted');
                            continue;
                        }
                        
                        if (latestTaskInIteration == null)
                        {
                            latestTaskInIteration = taskForThis;
                        }
                        
                        if (taskForThis.CreatedDate > latestTaskInIteration.CreatedDate)
                        {
                            latestTaskInIteration = taskForThis;
                        }
                    }
                    system.debug(latestTaskInIteration);
                    
                    if (latestTaskInIteration == null)
                    {
                        opp.Latest_Task_Open__c = false;
                    }
                    else if (latestTaskInIteration.Status != 'Completed')
                    {                  
                        opp.Latest_Task_Open__c = true;
                    }
                    oppsToUpdate.add(opp);
                }    
            }
            
        }
        
        update oppsToUpdate;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        system.debug('Error: ' + e.getMessage() + ' LineNumber: ' + e.getLineNumber()
            + '<br /> currentTask: ' + JSON.serialize(currentTask));
    }
    
    static List<Id> getOppIdsForTasks(List<Task> tasks)
    {
        List<Id> oppIds = new List<Id>();
        for (Task t: tasks)
        {
            if (t.TaskSubtype == 'Task' && t.WhatId != null && t.WhatId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName() == 'Opportunity')
            {
                oppIds.add(t.WhatId);   
            }
        }
        
        return oppIds;
    }
    
    static Map<Id, List<Task>> getMapOfTasksByOppId(List<Task> tasks)
    {
        Map<Id, List<Task>> mapToReturn = new Map<Id, List<Task>>();
        for (Task t: tasks)
        {
            List<Task> tasksForThis = mapToReturn.get(t.WhatId);
            if (tasksForThis == null)
            {
                tasksForThis = new List<Task>();
            }
            tasksForThis.add(t);
            mapToReturn.put(t.WhatId, tasksForThis);
        }
        
        return mapToReturn;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like the error is coming from the ActionPlans package. You could take a look at the source code to see if you can spot the issue: https://github.com/SalesforceLabs/ActionPlansV4/tree/main/sfdx-source/LabsActionPlans/main/default